# Get a string with %SystemRoot% does not present it CMD BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am querying from registry:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl" /v "DumpFile"') do set dump=%%i
```

When I do `echo %dump%` I get: `%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP`
But what I want is: `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP`

Because `%SystemRoot%` is built-in var which locates the SystemRoot (in this case `C:\Windows`)

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're reading REG_EXPAND_SZ value data, those should have an expandable variable in them, and this one does. The value data is being passed to you exactly as it is, if you wish to modify it you'll need to perform an additional action on `%%i`, to perform an additional expansion on it. **Technically your code is working absolutely correctly, and has no issues**, although I would advise that you change `3` to `2,*` and use `%%~j` for your result instead.

Comment: What is the additional expansion I need to perform on `%%i` or `%dump%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No explanation, just an answer:

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=2* %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl" /V "DumpFile" 2>NUL"')Do @Call Set "dump=%%~H"
```

If `Echo`ing is already turned off, and you can guarantee that the contents of your `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%` variables are unmodified on all systems this script will be run on, you can use the syntax below:

```batch-file
For /F "Tokens=2,*" %%i In ('Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl" /V "DumpFile" 2^>NUL') Do Call Set "dump=%%~j"
```

Comment: Well thanks that's worked! But, how can I do it with my syntax?

Comment: When I'm trying to edit my code it says: `2> was unexpected this time.`

Comment: @DanH, I have edited the answer above to use the similar syntax to what I believe you may be wanting, I will not bastardize it any more than that for you though.

Comment: I had not enough reputation but now I'm fine and gave you feedback, thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need reputation to accept an answer @DanH. Upvoting it suggests you found it useful, but it doesn't solve your issue. As it is the only answer here, and because I know it solves your issue, _(as long as you have not bastardized it)_, you should have marked it as accepted. The information on how to do so is clearly contained within the link I provided.

Comment: Done my friend :)